# Can't Parse XML file, no such file or directory

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse traffic data.  This is my first attempt at parsing XML so please be kind!

I have this code -

```
SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = null;
        try {
            parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler();
        try {
            parser.parse(new FileInputStream("http://m.highways.gov.uk/feeds/rss/AllEvents.xml"), handler);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In my manifest I have -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But when I run the app in the emulator it never asks for permission like locations does.  The error I get is -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/m.highways.gov.uk/feeds/rss/AllEvents.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Why does it miss a / after http:/?  Is that the problem?  Try the url, you will see there is data there.

What am I doing wrong please?  (I've searched but only find info on reading from a memory card)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`http://m.highways.gov.uk/feeds/rss/AllEvents.xml` is not a file on the filesystem. It is a URL to a document hosted on a Web server.

Either:

- Use an HTTP client API to download the XML to a file, then parse the file, or
- Use an HTTP client API to get an `InputStream` that you pass directly to `parse()`

Comment: Thanks, I had  -  parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("http://m.highways.gov.uk/feeds/rss/AllEvents.xml"), handler);   but that gives me an error that InputStream connect be null?  This was the syntax in the tutorial I've been following.  But then again, I think they have the XML file on the system, not the internet.  What should the line be please?

Comment: @AndyCr15: `parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("m.highwa‌​ys.gov.uk/feeds/rss/‌​AllEvents.xml"), handler);` is, at best, extraordinarily unusual for Android. "I think they have the XML file on the system, not the internet" -- then you should start by looking on your computer for the file, or downloading it from that URL. Save it as a raw resource or an asset in your project, and then use the associated `InputStream` (`getResources().openRawResource()` or `getAssets().open()`).